# Partial fillna with condition python

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I have the following data frame which I want to apply bfill as follows:

| 'amount' | 'percentage' |
| --- | --- |
| Nan |  |
| 1.0 | 20 |
| 2.0 | 10 |
| Nan |  |
| Nan |  |
| Nan |  |
| Nan |  |
| 3.0 | 50 |
| 4.0 | 10 |
| Nan |  |
| 5.0 | 10 |

I want to bfill Nan in the amount column as per percentage in the percentage column i.e., if the corresponding percentage is 50 then fill 50% of Nan before the number (partial fill). e.g. amount with 3.0 value have a percentage of 50 so out of 4 Nan entries, only 50% are to be bfill.

proposed output:

| 'amount' | 'percentage' |
| --- | --- |
| Nan |  |
| 1.0 | 20 |
| 2.0 | 10 |
| Nan |  |
| Nan |  |
| 3.0 |  |
| 3.0 |  |
| 3.0 | 50 |
| 4.0 | 10 |
| Nan |  |
| 5.0 | 10 |

Please help.

Comment: Share the code that you have developed and the errors that you are getting when you run that code, anyone will do the work that you are suposed to do.

Answer (score 4):

Create groups according to `NaN`s

```
df['group_id'] = df.amount.where(df.amount.isna(), 1).cumsum().bfill()
```

Create a filling function

```
def custom_fill(x):

    # Calculate number of rows to be filled
    max_fill_rows = math.floor(x.iloc[-1, 1] * (x.shape[0] - 1) / 100)

    # Fill only if number of rows to fill is not zero
    return x.bfill(limit=max_fill_rows) if max_fill_rows else x
```

Fill the DataFrame

```
df.groupby('group_id').apply(custom_fill)
```

Output

```
   amount  percentage group_id
0     NaN         NaN      1.0
1     1.0        20.0      1.0
2     2.0        10.0      2.0
3     NaN         NaN      3.0
4     NaN         NaN      3.0
5     3.0        50.0      3.0
6     3.0        50.0      3.0
7     3.0        50.0      3.0
8     4.0        10.0      4.0
9     NaN         NaN      5.0
10    5.0        10.0      5.0
```

PS: Don't forget to import the required libraries

```
import math
```

Comment: Thanks but bfill not working as it should have. (No Nan in amount are filled)

Comment: @MayurZambare -This solution does work with your example (or similar) data. Only limitation is that the `percantage` column has to be the second in your dataframe. You can change `x.iloc[-1, 1]` to `x.iloc[-1].loc['percentage']` to work with different column layouts.

Comment: Yeah. Please customize according to your data. I can only guide you. @MayurZambare. Please follow Michael's solution.

Comment: @Vishnudev I have traied that but still Nan are not filled. I am using Pandas version 1.2.4.

Comment: @MayurZambare You need to do `df['amount'] = df.amount.replace('Nan', np.nan)` before all this. Since the `NaN` in your column is a string Nan.